# How to trigger async job from a Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Cloud Function (Python) which is triggered by `http` from web client, it has to calculate something and respond **FAST**. I would like to save the `http` request parameters into a database (for analytics).

If i just initiate a WRITE to my `postgresql`, the function will have to wait for it, and it will be **slower**.

Using PubSub, the Function also need to publish and wait for respond (Docs example) :

```
   # Publishes a message
    try:
        publish_future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=message_bytes)
        publish_future.result()  # Verify the publish succeeded
        return 'Message published.'
```

Google does not offer a solution which trigger **in the background automatically** a pubSub when a `http` function is called.

How can I take information from my function and save it to my DB (any DB) **without affecting the function execution** at all.

```
def cloud_func(request):

      request_json = request.get_json()
        //save to db async without waiting for respond
        //calculate my stuff..
        return (result, 200, headers) //to client
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a Cloud Functions trigger in HTTP, I recommend you to migrate to [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs), and to activate the [always on CPU](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation) parameter.

That parameter is designed exactly for that: continue a process in background even outside a request handling context

---

**EDIT 1**

You can also imagine an async mechanism by staying on Cloud Functions. The sync function get the data from the user, publish a message in PubSub and answer to the user.

The PubSub message publication is very fast, and won't take too much time.

Then write another function, that listen the PubSub topic and save the message data into your database. Because that function is async, you are not time constraints.

Comment: I have a whole system on Cloud Function, do you advice me to move all of it out just to be able to send async request? is there any other advantage to learn a whole new thing now and move there?

Comment: is there, btw, a way to actually send info from a Function to a DB without spending too much time? (like saving directly to a db which is synced) i want clients to get respond and not wait for me to save analytics.

Comment: I prefer Cloud RUn to Cloud functions, for many reason and even if one of my [first article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-cloud-function-what-i-use-and-why-12bb5d3798e1) is pretty old, many arguments are still valid. In addition, I proposed you (in my answer) another design that let you keep using Cloud functions

Comment: Thank you very much, i posted about it, and actually the publish of pubsub is slow, and since my function is a part of a search engine, it makes it slower a bit. Please see from yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72048941/pubsub-from-a-function-published-in-the-background/72049315#72049315