# Pubsub from a Function published in the background?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

The whole reason I use PubSub is in order to **not** make my Cloud Function to wait, so things happens auto. To publish a `topic` from a Function, the code Google Docs show is :

```
# Publishes a message to a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
def publish(topic_name,message):

     # Instantiates a Pub/Sub client
    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
    if not topic_name or not message:
        return ('Missing "topic" and/or "message" parameter.', 400)

    # References an existing topic
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path(PROJECT_ID, topic_name)

    message_json = json.dumps({
        'data': {'message': message},
    })
    message_bytes = message_json.encode('utf-8')

    # Publishes a message
    try:
        publish_future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=message_bytes)
        publish_future.result()  # Verify the publish succeeded
        return 'Message published.'
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return (e, 500)
```

Which means Function is waiting for respond, but i want my Function to spend 0 seconds on this. How can I publish and forget ? not wait for respond? (without more dependencies?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the comments in the code, it is waiting to make sure that the publish **succeeded**.  It's not waiting for any sort of response from any of the subscribers on that topic.  It's extremely important the code wait until the publish succeeds, otherwise the message might not actually be sent at all, and you risk losing that data entirely.  This is because Cloud Functions terminates the code and locks down CPU and I/O after the function returns.

If you really want to risk it, you could try removing the call to `result()`, but I don't think it's a good idea if you want a reliable system.

Comment: Thank you Doug, is this slower or faster than just writing a single word into my SQL/Storage ? does it actually wait for some signal from a remote server? because i need to send data without spending time on this Function, so is the pubsub operation faster than just saving a word into a db ?

Comment: I do feel it makes things slower a bit, and speed here is very important (it is like a search engine that need to save queries for analytics). Maybe it is better to just call the other Function without waiting for respond?

Comment: If you want to know if something is comparatively fast or slow to something else, you should run benchmarks against each option.  I can't tell you how your specific setup is going to behave.  The issue from my point of view is reliability.  Either you wait for the information to be saved somewhere, or you risk losing it entirely.  I strongly suggest you wait for it to be saved.

Comment: Say i don't want to wait and don't care to lose it here and there (just analytics) does not waiting means more chance to lose data?

Comment: As I said, by not waiting for the message to be queued, there is a risk of it being dropped completely. You will have to perform your own tests to see what the actual probability is.

Comment: Thank you Doug for your time, really. Just last one, say this Function is a search engine, which mean it needs to provide results ASAP, but I also want to save user http parameters in that Function. What route would you go which is the fastest  to save it before(after?) responding?

Comment: Well turned out writing to db takes much less time than publishing. it is 0.006 seconds, so i will go with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule your functions to run at certain times of the day or every 'interval' time. In this example, this would go into your index.js file and deployed to your functions.

The code would run 'every minute' in the background. The error would simply return to your logs in google cloud console.

If you are using firestore and need to manage documents, you can make the function run on specific events like on document create or update etc..

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

EDIT: Not exactly sure if this example matches your use case but hope this example helps

```
exports.scheduledFx = functions.pubsub.schedule('every minute').onRun(async (context) => {

    // Cron time string Description
    // 30 * * * *   Execute a command at 30 minutes past the hour, every hour.
    // 0 13 * * 1   Execute a command at 1:00 p.m. UTC every Monday.
    // */5 * * * *  Execute a command every five minutes.
    // 0 */2 * * *  Execute a command every second hour, on the hour.
 
    
    try {
      //your code here
    
  
    } catch (error) {

      return error

    }
    
})
```

Comment: Thank you Yewla, i know this, but i need to actually chain functions to save analytics without spending time.